# XSD unique restriction selecting all ancestors of a node

Tags: xml, xpath, xsd

I am trying to define an XSD to reflect the structure of a certain kind of XML. Here's an example of such an XML:

```xml
<input id="x">
    <value id="x1">
        <input id="y">
            <value id="y1"/>
            <value id="y2"/>
        </input>
    </value>
    <value id="x2">
        <input id="y">
            <value id="y3"/>
            <value id="y4"/>
            <value id="y5"/>
        </input>
        <input id="z">
            <value id="z1"/>
            <value id="z2"/>
        </input>
    </value>
</input>
```

This represents the following:

- Each `input` is a combobox that has a series of entries (`value`s) inside.
- Each `value` is an entry in a combobox. If it has `input`s inside, it means that those inputs should be displayed when this value is selected in its corresponding combobox.

So the example above means:

- There's a combobox *x* that contains entries *x1* and *x2*
- If *x1* is selected:

  - a combobox *y* is displayed, containing entries *y1* and *y2*
- If *x2* is selected:

  - a combobox *y* is displayed, containing entries *y3*, *y4* and *y5*
  - a combobox *z* is displayed, containing entries *z1* and *z2*

There can be arbitrary nesting, that is, any `value` could contain more `input`s, which could contain more `value`s, etc. This is all good and clear. My problem is that I want to define a `unique` restriction to guarantee that it is not possible to specify a situation where there are multiple inputs with the same `id` being displayed at the same time. That is, an `input` cannot have any ancestors that have the same `id` as that `input`. For example:

```xml
<input id="x"> <!-- illegal -->
    <value id="x1">
        <input id="x"> <!-- illegal -->
            <value id="y1"/>
            <value id="y2"/>
        </input>
    </value>
    ...
</input>
```

This is illegal because there's an input *x* inside another input *x*

```xml
<input id="x"> <!-- illegal -->
    <value id="x1">
        <input id="y">
            <value id="y1">
                <input id="x"> <!-- illegal -->
                    <value id="z1"/>
                    <value id="z2"/>
                </input>
            </value>
            <value id="y2"/>
        </input>
    </value>
    ...
</input>
```

This is illegal because of the same reason. It doesn't matter how many nodes there are between the two *x* inputs in the hierarchy; it's not allowed.

However, this is legal:

```xml
<input id="x">
    <value id="x1">
        <input id="y"> <!-- legal -->
            <value id="y1"/>
            <value id="y2"/>
        </input>
    </value>
    <value id="x2">
        <input id="y"> <!-- legal -->
            <value id="y3"/>
            <value id="y4"/>
            <value id="y5"/>
        </input>
        <input id="z">
            <value id="z1"/>
            <value id="z2"/>
        </input>
    </value>
</input>
```

The two *y* inputs are in different hierarchies, so there's no conflict.

I struggle to find to XPath expression to use in the `unique` restriction: this seems to be what I'm looking for...

```xml
<xs:unique name="uniqueInputIdInBranch">
    <xs:selector xpath="ancestor-or-self::input"/>
    <xs:field xpath="@id"/>
</xs:unique>
```

...but this kind of XPath doesn't seem to be allowed in XSD. I get:

> The expression 'ancestor-or-self::input' is not valid with respect to the XPath subset supported by XML Schema.

Afaict my selector should go upwards in the ancestor hierarchy rather than downwards...

```xml
<xs:unique name="uniqueInputIdInBranch">
    <xs:selector xpath=".//input"/>
    <xs:field xpath="@id"/>
</xs:unique>
```

...because going downwards will not distinguish between "branches" and will report this as invalid, even though the two *y* inputs are in different branches:

```xml
<input id="x">
    <value id="x1">
        <input id="y"> <!-- legal but marked as illegal -->
            <value id="y1"/>
            <value id="y2"/>
        </input>
    </value>
    <value id="x2">
        <input id="y"> <!-- legal but marked as illegal -->
            <value id="y3"/>
            <value id="y4"/>
            <value id="y5"/>
        </input>
        <input id="z">
            <value id="z1"/>
            <value id="z2"/>
        </input>
    </value>
</input>
```

Is there a way to implement the "unique within branch" validation I describe above? Here's the XSD so far, in case you want to play with it:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    targetNamespace="test"
    xmlns:tns="test"
    elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xs:element name="inputs" type="tns:inputsType"/>

    <xs:complexType name="inputsType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="input" type="tns:inputType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="inputType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="value" type="tns:valueType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:unique name="uniqueInputIdInBranch">
                    <xs:selector xpath="ancestor-or-self::input"/>
                    <xs:field xpath="@id"/>
                </xs:unique>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:token" use="required"/>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="valueType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="input" type="tns:inputType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:token" use="required"/>
    </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

Sorry for the long post, and thanks!

Comment: I think your xpath fails because `input` is an [empty element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input): `Permitted content  None, it is an empty element.` so `ancestor-or-self::input` is invalid since `input` could be an ancestor of your current tag which is an input itself.

Comment: @LuisMuñoz The `input` reference you linked is for the *HTML* `input` element. I'm not working with HTML but XML. If you replace all the `input` in my XML and XSD with a different tag name you'll still get the same error... Afaict from the error I get and from the specs I've looked at, `ancestor-or-self::input` is simply not supported by XSD's XPath subset. Thanks, though! :)